# .NET MVC on github

Tags: asp.net-mvc, github-for-windows

I built a very simple .net MVC web project on Visual Studio 2013. I then pushed it to Github, when I cloned my project back onto my machine and tried to run it (on the same version of Visual Studio 2013) I got a lot of errors including:

"The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

"The type or namespace name 'Authorize' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

and many more (there are about 170 of those)

I also removed .gitignore at some point, just to be sure, it didn't help.

Comment: Have you uploaded `packages` folder? You can enable `nuget package restore` to restore packages automatically

Comment: I misplaced packages folder. It is all working after I added it to Github. Thank you very much Vsevolod Goloviznin!!

p.s Is there any way of avoiding having to upload all these packages? (Sorry if this is a silly question im new to .net) like when i worked with Node.js i didnt have to upload all the huge node modules, they were stored as dependencies and could be installed by the means of a short command.

Thanks again.

Comment: Check the answer below, there is package restore option

Answer (score 1):

Based on the info above, it would appear that your Nuget packages have not been re-downloaded.

You could Enable Nuget package Restore (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore)

Or you could install each package from the Nuget window.